# how to get the total documents count and specific type of document count?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find total occurrence of specific type of category and sum of all categories selected. right now, I can get is total count of selected categories, but I also want total occurrence of specific categories and group documents every hour basis.
P.S I'm new to mongo dB

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      categories: {
        $in: categories
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      uniqueHour: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%H",
          date: "$publishedAt"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      categories: categories
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        hour: "$uniqueHour"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: -1
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: please add some sample input json data with your expected outpout

Comment: {
"publishedAt":
"2022-12-07T06:43:18.000+00:00",
"categories": ["Web Design"]
}
categories are different.like some 2D animation, 3D animation, Web design. i want to count how many times a specific category occur and want to count all the categories occurrence

Comment: You are looking for something simple as [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T9SkqhiSOCY)?

Comment: @ray.no, suppose i have [{ "publishedAt": "2022-12-07T06:43:18.000+00:00", "categories": ["Web Design"] },{ "publishedAt": "2022-12-07T06:43:18.000+00:00", "categories": ["Full stack development"] },{ "publishedAt": "2022-12-07T06:43:18.000+00:00", "categories": ["Full stack development"] },{ "publishedAt": "2022-12-07T06:43:18.000+00:00", "categories": ["web developer"] }]
i want to count specific categories count and all categories count 
like AllCategoriesCount =4, fullstackcount =2, webdeveloper = 1. something like this